# In chrome browser data not loading but in Firefox browser data is loading

Tags: xml, selenium, testng

I'm trying to run testcases in different browser at same time, but while doing this chrome browser is opening but data not loading at the same firefox browser opening and data also loading.

Eg: Trying to opening the gmail.com page.

Below the testng.xml:

```
 <test name="ChromeTest"> 
     <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
     <classes>
     <class name="website.Hello" /> 
     </classes>
 </test>

 <test name="FirefoxTest">
     <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" /> 
     <classes>
     <class name="website.Hello" />
     </classes>
 </test>
```

BaseTest code:

```
public class BaseTest {  

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest

    @Parameters("browser")

    public void setup(String browser) throws Exception{

        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){

        //create firefox instance

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }

        //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'

        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

            //set path to chromedriver.exe You may need to download it from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\DesktopFrameWork\\WatchableDesktop\\resources\\chromedriver_Windows.exe");

            //create chrome instance

            driver = new ChromeDriver();

           // driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        }

        else{

            //If no browser passed throw exception

            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");

        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
```

}

Comment: Show your code how are you creating your drivers

Comment: @karthikashoka what do you mean by running test case at the same time. Are you trying run it in parallel. if so, I don't see anything like that in your testng.xml file.